# why is $\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f'}{f} = \mathbb{Z}-\mathbb{P}$? why not $\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f'}{f} = \mathbb{P}?$

Tags: complex-analysis

Theorem $10.8$

> Suppose  $\gamma $ is  a regular closed  curve. If $f$  is meromorphic inside and on $\gamma$  and  contains no zeroes  or oples  on $\gamma$ , and if

> $\mathbb{Z}$= number of zeroes  of  $f$  inside  $\gamma$ ( a  zero of order k being  counted  $k$  times

> $\mathbb{P}=$ number  of poles of $f$  inside $\gamma$ (again with multiplicity)

then  $$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f'}{f} = \mathbb{Z}-\mathbb{P}$$

---

**My confusion** :why is $\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f'}{f} = \mathbb{Z}-\mathbb{P}$? why not $\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f'}{f} = \mathbb{P}?$

---

**My attempt** :At  a simple pole  $a$ , the residue of $f$ is given by  $Res(f,a)=\lim_{z\to a}f(z)$

$$\implies Res(\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)},a)=\lim_{z\to a} (z-a) \frac{k}{z-a}+ \lim_{z\to a} (z-a)\frac{g'(z)}{g(z)}$$
$$\implies Res(\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)},a)= k$$

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f'}{f}= \sum_k Res (\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)},a_k)=\underbrace{k+k+...+k}_{k- \text{times}}=k^2=\text{ number  of poles of f  inside} \gamma=\mathbb{P}$$

Im not getting why is  $\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f'}{f} = \mathbb{Z}-\mathbb{P}?$

Comment: $f'/f$ has poles at points where $f=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(z)=z$, then $f$ has *zero* poles. But $\dfrac{f'(z)}{f(z)}=\frac1z$ and $\displaystyle\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=1}=1$. And $1$ *is* the number of zeros minus the number of poles ($1-0$). So, there is no way the right formula is $\displaystyle\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=1}=\Bbb P$. Besides, the poles of $\dfrac{f'}f$ are the poles and the zeros of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking only at poles of $f$.  You have to compute the residues of $\frac {f'} f$ at the zeros of $f$ also.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation of the residues is wrong. At a $k$-fold pole of $f$ is
$$
 f(z) = (z-a)^{-k} g(z)
$$
where $g$ is holomorphic and non-zero in a neighborhood of $z=a$. Therefore
$$
 \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} = \frac{-k}{z-a} + \text{ something holomorphic }
$$
in a neighborhood of $z=a$, so that
$$
\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)},a\right) = -k \, .
$$
Similarly,
$$
\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)},a\right) = +k \, .
$$
at a $k$-fold zero of $f$.

Adding these contributions over all zeros and poles inside the contour gives the wanted formula.

Note also that this formula is only valid for a *simple* (i.e. non-self-intersection and positively oriented) closed curve, otherwise you have to take the winding numbers of $\gamma$  with respect to the zeros and poles into account.